# How do I change the link of an image using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, web, url

I have a site at https://arvikamagasinet.com

At the top, there is a header image/banner, which links to the original homepage. I would like to change the link so that the header image links to a specific URL.

I need to use CSS to edit this. There is no built-in function in WordPress to change the URL-link of the header image.

Thanks in advance,
Sakeus

Comment: You cannot change html link using css. You need to modify wordpress template.

Comment: CSS is for styling, it can't change content.

Answer (score 0):

the matter is very easy, you should go to your Wordpress theme folder in wp-content then you will find the header.php which display the header or you can search for it in index.php and you find the image and you will find that code :

```
<a href="https://arvikamagasinet.com/" title="Arvikamagasinet" rel="home" class="header-image">
            <img src="https://arvikamagasinet.files.wordpress.com/2020/09/untitled-6-2.png" width="1250" height="400" alt="">
        </a>
```

you will change a href to your ned link :

```
<a href="link here" title="Arvikamagasinet" rel="home" class="header-image">
            <img src="https://arvikamagasinet.files.wordpress.com/2020/09/untitled-6-2.png" width="1250" height="400" alt="">
        </a>
```